# jquery callback variable returns "undefined"

Tags: jquery, loops, callback, undefined

I'm a designer, not a programer and I'm trying to get used to jquery and javascript for some experiments(animation)... so far I managed a few things, but I really don't get any further at this point: I'm trying to add callbacks in the loop to have each animation step finish before the next one starts. The problem is that in this case the pick variable returns "undefined" as soon as I put it in the callback. I guess it's really simple to solve, but I've been searching the web for hours, and just can't manage to get it to work.

any help would be appreciated.

```
for (i = 0; i < pick.length; i++)
{
    target= $('#'+pick[i]).css('left');
    console.log(target+'no1');

    $('#'+pick[i]).animate({'left':farright}, 1000, function () {
        $('#'+pick[i]).css('left', farleft, function () {
            $('#'+pick[i]).animate({'left':target}, 3000);
        });
     });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pick.each( function() {
    target= this.css('left');
    console.log(target+'no1');

    this.animate({'left':farright}, 1000, function () {
        this.css('left', farleft, function () {
            this.animate({'left':target}, 3000);
        });
     });  
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

I dont honestly know if it solves your certain problem but its much more elegant to use if youre using JQuery anyway